# UNAUTHENTICATED issue while connecting to Google Firestore

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

I am using the Google Cloud Firestore Beta and wrote a very simple code based on the documentation provided by google. I am getting an UNAUTHENTICATED error while executing it. The code is as below and is very similar to some of the snippets provided in the documentation.

```
String keyPath = "mykeystore.json";
FirestoreOptions firestoreOptions = FirestoreOptions.getDefaultInstance().toBuilder().setProjectId("test-project-111").setCredentials(ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream(keyPath))).build();
Firestore db = firestoreOptions.getService();
DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("users").document("alovelace");
// Add document data  with id "alovelace" using a hashmap
Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
data.put("first", "Ada");
data.put("last", "Lovelace");
data.put("born", 1815);
//asynchronously write data
ApiFuture<WriteResult> result = docRef.set(data);
try 
{
    result.get();
} catch (InterruptedException e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ExecutionException e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}

I am getting the error at the "result.get()" line of the code. The error is as below:
```

[INFO] GCLOUD: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnauthenticatedException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAUTHENTICATED

Comment: Sharing the complete stack trace here:

Comment: Validate your firestore Api key & Id https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/solutions/search

Answer (score 0):

> UNAUTHENTICATED issue while connecting to Google Firestore

**Beta**

This is a beta release of Cloud Firestore. This product might be changed in backward-incompatible ways and is not subject to any SLA or deprecation policy.

[Cloud Firestore is currently in beta release](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/). Feature availability and support for product integrations and platforms will continue to improve as the product matures. For more information on existing limitations in Cloud Firestore, see the limits and quotas documentation

**OR** Validate your firestore Api key & Id
[Cloud Firestore Security Rules](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/security/get-started)